Identify the property to distinguish among different materials
Context: My son is studying in 6th grade, he got a question like this in a competitive examination.

Vinegar, lemon juice, wheat flour, diesel and mustard oil can be distinguished on the basis of a property called

Hardness
Appearance
Solubility
Magnetism


Son answered 2. Appearance and as per their key, the answer is 3. Solubility
Which is correct and why? Or are all of them wrong?

Clarification:
I am ok with the question being closed. But I didn't like the way it was closed off as a homework question.
The thing is, this question is not a homework question. This was asked in a competitive examination. I was baffled by both the question and the answer key.
How can I clarify something that I don't have any clarity about? :)

That's a dreadful question. I don't see how solubility would allow vinegar and lemon juice to be distinguished, except for the fact that lemon juice contains suspended particles. We rarely make decisions based on one feature. I would also have answered appearance, but odor, density, viscosity, pH, solubility would be useful. Magnetism and hardness would not be very.

You can distinguish them all by appearance.
You would have difficulties to differentiate by solubility

the water based solutions like vinegar and lemon juice
oily substances like diesel and plant oil.

The answer why the answer 3 and not 2 has been  chosen can be provided only by the author of the question.
Numbers 1 and 4 are obvious and total nonsenses.


There is an argument that "appearance" is not a property. How valid is that?

It is half true, as appearance consists of a set of objective and subjective properties.

Flour being solid is both the subjective and objective property.
Low viscosity (vinegar, lemon juice) is both subjective and objective property.
Producing acidic vapor (vinegar) is both subjective and objective property.
Not being fully clear solution (lemon juice) is both subjective and objective property.
Having technical smell (diesel) is subjective property. Objective property would require instrumentation.

Solubility is objective property, but it would distingush just three groups:

Water solutions (vinegar, lemon juice)
Oily substances insoluble in water (diesel, mustard oil)
Insoluble solids (flour)


Hardness is a parameter that is only valid for water containing a small amount of calcium or magnesium ions. It cannot be measured in a fruit juice, or in oils.
Appearance is a criteria difficult to define for a given substance. Is it the colour, the density, the melting point ? A combination of these parameters ?
Solubility has no meaning here, because, first, vinegar and lemon juice are already both solutions. Solutions don't have any solubility. Then, wheat is not a pure substance. Only pure substances have a measured solubility. Third, Diesel and mustard oil are all insoluble in water : their low solubility can be determined, but it is rather low, and often not known with precision.
